# Add element to array associative arrays

Tags: javascript, associative-array

[All](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936636/js-associative-arrays-add-new-pair) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351495/dynamically-creating-keys-in-javascript-associative-array) of adding new elements to associative arrays are going the "easy" way and just have a one dimensional array - my problem of understanding is having arrays within arrays (or is it objects in arrays?).

I have the following array:

```
var test = [
            {
                value: "FirstVal",
                label: "My Label 1"
            },
            {
                value: "SecondVal",
                label: "My Label 2"
            }
           ];
```

Two questions: How to generate this array of associative arrays (yes... object) **from scratch**? How to **add a new element** to an existing array?

Thanks for helping me understand javascript.

Comment: What does _from scratch_ mean?

Comment: This might be useful: [Javascript: Adding to an associative array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328508/javascript-adding-to-an-associative-array/8328541#8328541)

Comment: Bad wording... "from scratch" simply meaning - new. Basically it is the same as starting with an empty array and adding elements to it - your replies already answer this :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "from scratch", but this would work:

```
var test = [];  // new array

test.push({
                value: "FirstVal",
                label: "My Label 1"
            });  // add a new object

test.push({
                value: "SecondVal",
                label: "My Label 2"
            });  // add a new object
```

Though the syntax you posted is a perfectly valid way of creating it "from scratch".

And adding a new element would work the same way `test.push({..something...});`.

Answer (score 4):

This is an array of objects.

You can put more objects in it by calling `test.push({ ... })`

Comment: "array of objects" - thanks for clarifying! Basically non-named objects, because of the {}?

Comment: @moontear: There is no such thing as a "named object".

Answer (score 2):

```
var items = [{name:"name1", data:"data1"}, 
             {name:"name2", data:"data2"}, 
             {name:"name3", data:"data3"}, 
             {name:"name4", data:"data4"}, 
             {name:"name5", data:"data5"}]

var test = [];

for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    var item = {};
    item.label = items[i].name;
    item.value = items[i].data;
    test.push(item);
}
```

makes **test** equal to

```
[{label:"name1", value:"data1"}, 
 {label:"name2", value:"data2"}, 
 {label:"name3", value:"data3"}, 
 {label:"name4", value:"data4"}, 
 {label:"name5", value:"data5"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

From scratch, the following lines will create an populate an array with objects, using the [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method:

```
var test = [];          // Create an array
var obj = {};           // Create an object
obj.value = "FirstVal"; // Add values, etc.
test.push(obj);
```

Comment: Please fix your script to use newobj too